# PyCharm hotkey to indent/un-indent a line at caret?

Tags: pycharm, hotkeys

Currently we can move a line up/down by `alt`+`shift`+`UP` and  `alt`+`shift`+`DOWN`

Though, when we have moved the line to target position and want to indent it, we have to go to the beginning of the line to `tab`/`shift-tab`.

I wonder if we can do that right away at caret position i.e. without having to move to the begin of line.

p.s.

[My google](https://www.google.com.vn/?ion=1&espv=2#q=PyCharm%20hotkey%20to%20indent%2Fun-indent%20a%20line%20at%20caret) results as [this page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/changing-indentation.html) put `ctrl`+`alt`+`I` not work for me.

Comment: If you select a single character on the line, tab/shift tab will do the entire line.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As @cdbajorin [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39192842/pycharm-hotkey-to-indent-un-indent-a-line-at-caret?noredirect=1#comment65726303_39192842), it's just one more step - selecting a character to indent whole line i.e. no-selection will indent text on the right only.

```
If you select a single character on the line, tab/shift tab will do the
```

Comment: selecting a character is the key, I was used to vs code where just keeping the cursor does the indent work.

Comment: @ChandanNayak What is your point about vscode, I don't get it?

Comment: I wanted to say - on vs code I do not have to select any character by just placing the cursor anywhere on the line and hit cmd + }/{ to do the indent. But with pycharm i needed to select a word/character to do the indent. Because it just tabs outward from the cursor with pycharm.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for sharing. But working with Python the opensource way, vscode from microsoft should not be the IDE for us I think.

Comment: there is a keymap named "indent Line or Selection",it dont need to select any text @ChandanNayak

Answer (score 1):

By default, the tab key execute action "**indent Selection**",so you must select some text.
there is a keymap named "**indent Line or Selection**", you can use tab as its shortcut.then you dont need to select text
(my pycharm version:2020.1.3)